# Get a subset of an array based on an array of keys

Tags: php, arrays, higher-order-functions

I wrote this function to get a subset of an array. Does php have a built in function for this. I can't find one in the docs. Seems like a waste if I'm reinventing the wheel.

```
function array_subset($array, $keys) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $result[$key] = $array[$key];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array function that returns a subset for given keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543361/php-array-function-that-returns-a-subset-for-given-keys)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`array_diff_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) and [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) are probably what you want.

Comment: The function names are singular. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

PHP needs to clean up their naming conventions!

Comment: When you're mapping keys in an associative array to lookup table of values in a non-associative array, you can use `array_flip` on one argument to ensure that the intersection/diff is based on either both keys or both values, not a mix of one or the other.

Answer (score 15):

I always want this too. Like a PHP version of Underscore's [pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick).

It's ugly and counter-intuitive, but what I sometimes do is this (I think this may be what prodigitalson was getting at):

```
$a = ['foo'=>'bar', 'zam'=>'baz', 'zoo'=>'doo'];

// Extract foo and zoo but not zam
print_r(array_intersect_key($a, array_flip(['foo', 'zoo'])));
/*
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [zoo] => doo
)
*/
```

[array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) returns all the elements of the first argument whose keys are present in the 2nd argument (and all subsequent arguments, if any). But, since it compares keys to keys, I use [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) for convenience. I could also have just used `['foo' => null, 'zoo' => null]` but that's even uglier.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct function I think in PHP to get a subset from an `array1` with compare to another `array2` where the values are the list of key name which we fetch.

Like: `array_only($array1, 'field1','field2');`

But this way can be achieved the same.

```
<?php

$associative_array = ['firstname' => 'John', 'lastname' => 'Smith', 'DOB' => '2000-10-10', 'country' => 'Ireland' ];

$subset = array_intersect_key( $associative_array, array_flip( [ 'lastname', 'country' ] ) );

print_r( $subset );

// Outputs...
// Array ( [lastname] => Smith [country] => Ireland );
```