# PHP: Get array values of a string array that match substrings of another string array

Tags: php, arrays, string

There are two arrays:

```
$strings = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange');
$substrings = array('pp', 'range');
```

I want to get an array which contains all the strings, that match the substrings:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [2] => Orange
)
```

Or with new indices:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => Orange
)
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Wow, this works better than *coders for hire*!

Comment: @jeroen everyone is keen to jump on low hanging fruit like this. Gotta get them rep points!

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543361/php-array-function-that-returns-a-subset-for-given-keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution that comes to mind: combine [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) and [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos);

```
$strings = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange');
$substrings = array('pp', 'range');

$result = array_filter($strings, function($item) use($substrings) {
  foreach($substrings as $substring)
    if(strpos($item, $substring) !== FALSE) return TRUE;
  return FALSE;
});
```

To reset indices, you can use the [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) function.

Comment: I don't really understand the "function($item) use($substrings)" part, but it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Ben: It's a [anonymous function/closure](http://php.net/closures)

Answer (score 1):

```
$strings = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange');
$substrings = array('pp', 'range');
$newarray = array();

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    foreach ($substrings as $substring) {
        if (strstr($string, $substring)) {
            array_push($newarray, $string);
        }
    }
}
```

in `$newarray` you have the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) for this:

```
$strings = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange');
$substrings = array('pp', 'range');

$result = array_filter($strings, function($string) use ($substrings){
    foreach($substrings as $substring)
        if(strstr($string, $substring) !== false)
            return true;
    return false;
});

// $result is the result you want.
```

Comment: Be careful, `strstr` might return the string `"0"` which is considered false-y

Comment: @knittl Ah, didn't consider the case where a substring might be "0". Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

try array_search. looked at the second note at the bottom of this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=array();
foreach($substrings as $item)
{
    $result=array_keys($strings,$item);
    if ($result)
    {
        $arr=array_merge($arr,$result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work for matching the whole of a string, but not for partial matches such as 'pp' and 'rang' as was mentioned.